# Не переведены элементы меню по закрытию вопроса на Мете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

На Мете не переведены некоторые элементы меню, с помощью которого выбирается причина закрытия вопроса.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По варианту “Other...” варианты предлагаются здесь: [Не переведены элементы меню по закрытию вопроса на основном сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1005/181472)

Для сравнения, на основном сайте аналогичный текст выглядит так:

> Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow на русском, согласно правилам описанным в справке.

Answer (score 1):

> This question does not appear to be about RU Stack Overflow Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the справка.

**на основе аналогичного пункта на основном сайте (с актуализацией ссылки)**:

Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта *Stack Overflow на русском*, ни к программному обеспечению сети *Stack Exchange*, согласно правилам, описанным в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: О, с «ни-ни» мне больше нравится формулировка. А вот про правила и на основном сайте, на мой взгяд, непонятно написано.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, приведённая мною ссылка является единственной подходящей под определение «правила для meta-сайта» во всей справочной системе.

Comment: в данный момент ведет на просто справку. Но я согласен, что ваша ссылка лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Источник:

> This question does not appear to be about RU Stack Overflow Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the справка.

Перевод:

> Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится к Stack Overflow на русском языке или к программному обеспечению, используемому сетью Stack Exchange, что составляет допустимый круг тем для Меты, согласно `[справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)`.

Ссылка заменена на более релевантную, по примеру ответа Alexander Barakin.