# Не переведены элементы меню по закрытию вопроса на основном сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

На основном сайте не переведены некоторые элементы меню, с помощью которого выбирается причина закрытия вопроса.

Закрытие — Не по теме — в конце списка два непереведенных пункта.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответах предлагайте варианты **перевода для каждой строки отдельно**.

Answer (score 1):

> Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

Другое (добавьте комментарий, объясняющий причину закрытия)

Answer (score 1):

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса.

---

Кстати, кроме Меты сюда неплохо бы добавить EN.SO — для тех случаев, когда пользователи путают сайты и задают вопрос на английском.

Comment: Возможность перенести вопрос на англоязычный Stack Overflow, как и в любое другое сообщество есть у модераторов уже сейчас. Для перенесения, пожалуйста, отметьте вопрос как требующий внимания модератора.

Answer (score 0):

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Этот вопрос надо переместить на другой сайт в сети *Stack Exchange*